# FileIO, writing to document, var = 1.0 becomes 1

Tags: c++, c++11

When I have the user input a section number (such as 1.1, 3.4, 4.23 etc), I need to be able to write section numbers to a .txt document that are inclusive of 1.0, where currently 1.0 is written as just an integer 1 (or 1.10 which is written as 1.1).

Doing this as a bunch of 'if' statements is messy, is there a better way?

Edit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Enter a float here" << endl;
  float f;
  cin >> f;

  ofstream fine;
  fine.open("fine.txt", ios::out);
  fine << f << "\n";
}
```

If you enter 1.0 as your float, it saves 1 to the .txt. What I need to be able to do is have the user enter in a number like 1.0, or 1.10, and have those be writable to the .txt as they are, not with the zero truncated.

Comment: Can you show the code used to write into the file please?

Comment: [mcve] please. Don't leave us guessing as to what your implementation looks like.

Comment: We cannot guess at a proper solution without knowing your constraints. What are the valid formats of a section number? Do you wish to perform validation? How about translation from a slightly erroneous input (e.g. 1.10) to a good one (e.g. 1.1)? You need to be _specific_.

Comment: You'll see the same thing if you write to `std::cout`. Use `std::setprecision(2)` to force two digits of precision in the output. Even better, as the answer I can see now says, use `std::string`.

Comment: @PeteBecker How to I "cout" to a .txt? I've never seen that before

Comment: The point is that this has nothing to do with writing to a file. All stream output will do the same thing, because that's how `operator<<` works.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not sure I understand. My need is to write to a file, so for me...it only has to do with writing to a file. Are you saying that if I cout while the ofstream is open that it will write to the file? If so, that's useful information that I wish I had had before lol

Answer (score 6):

`float` is a terrible choice to represent a "section number". If you use  `float` then §1.1 == §1.10 and §1.3.2 can't exist. Try `std::string` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout << "Enter a section number here" << endl;
  string f;
  cin >> f;

  ofstream fine;
  fine.open("fine.txt", ios::out);
  fine << f << "\n";
}
```